# Forwarding all input to Java Process

Tags: java, process, inputstream

I'm trying to forward the input to the process. It's a minecraft server so I need to send commands to it. I try in this way but it doesn't send anything. (I've also checked the log file)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("spigot.jar");
    if(file.exists()) {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "spigot.jar");
        Process p = builder.start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String s = "";
            try {
                while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(()-> {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String cmd = "";
            try {
                while((cmd = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    bw.write(cmd);
                    bw.flush();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            while(true) {
                if(!p.isAlive()) {
                    System.out.println("Server closed.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }).start();


    } else {
        System.out.println("spigot.jar not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I rewrote the code using threads but i'm getting the same problem

Comment: Time for you to learn and then use threading.

Comment: LOL. I didn't think about it. I'll try using different threads. sorry for this useless question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I need to add "bw.newline()" to send ENTER, and make the server execute my command